# Yii color picker change event issue

Tags: javascript, yii, color-picker

I'm using [minicolors color picker for Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minicolors-colorpicker/) and I want to attach a change event on the color picker input as always:

```
$('#color_picker').change(function(e) { console.log('It works!') });
```

But it doesn't work, then I tried:

```
$('#color_picker').miniColors({change: function(hex, rgb) { console.log('It works!') }});
```

This doesn't work either. Considering docs I should attach this event on creation, but why? What if I need to attach it after creation, can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have been missing the left-right parenthesis `{` `}` for the supplied `options`, here is what is described on [official document](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/)

```
$(selector).minicolors({
    change: function(hex, opacity) {
        console.log(hex + ' - ' + opacity);
    }
});
```

Edited (1):

```
<input id="general_bgColor" type="text">
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#general_bgColor').miniColors({ change: function(hex, rgb) { console.log('it worked!'); //console.log(hex + ' - ' + rgb); } });
    })
</script>
```

Edited (2): Here is what you should add using that Yii extension

```
$this->widget('ext.widgets.SMiniColors.SColorPicker', array(
    'id' => 'myInputId',
    'defaultValue'=>'#000000',
    'hidden'=>false, // defaults to false - can be set to hide the textarea with the hex
    'options' => array(
        'change' => 'js:function(hex, rgb) { console.log(hex + " - " + rgb); }'
    ), // jQuery plugin options
    'htmlOptions' => array(

    ), // html attributes
));
```

Notice my line option `'change'`.
I think the single quote on your function string inadvertently make invalid array. It makes the option key 'change' always has value '0'

Comment: $('#general_bgColor').miniColors({
    change: function(hex, rgb) { console.log(hex + ' - ' + rgb); }
});
This's what I have, miniColors's 'c' have to be capital (from Yii plugin) - this just doesn't work, no error

Comment: This was just my typo here

Comment: I have tried and it worked fine. I'm using same version Yii extension from http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minicolors-colorpicker/

Comment: You are binding the event on creation of miniColors plugin, aren't you?

Comment: Maybe I discovered what your problem was, please see my edit (2)

Comment: That's works, thank you! But it solves the issue partialy, can I add event listener after creation of plugin?

Comment: Yes, you could. It simply setup a snipet of js for reusable, nothing more nothing less. You even open the SColorPicker.php to see what was going on and how it works then you can customize it to fit your need later.

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't get it. Your solution works nice, but the aim was to bind event listener elsewhere, after initializing the widget, which, somewhy, doesn't work for me. 
*not modifying widget initializing code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35767/discussion-between-telvin-nguyen-and-colix)